# How to call function with args array without call_user_func_array?

Tags: php, callback

I need to call a function with arguments array, but call_user_func_array seems to be very slow for me.
I tried to use `ReflectionFunction` for that (see `code ex. 1`), but maybe there is another methods for that? It will be perfectly, if that method supports sorted parameters (see `code ex. 2`)

---

**code ex. 1**

```
private static function call(Callable $callable, array $args) {
    if(class_exists('ReflectionFunction', false)) {
        $r = (new ReflectionFunction($callable))->invokeArgs($args);
        # ROUTES_CALLBACK_STRATEGY may be "call" or "echo"
        if(defined('ROUTES_CALLBACK_STRATEGY') && strtolower(ROUTES_CALLBACK_STRATEGY) == 'call') {
            return;
        } else {
            echo $r;
        }
    } else {
        call_user_func_array($callable, $args);
    }
}
```

**code ex. 2**

```
$args = array(
    'param1' => 'p1',
    'param2' => 'p2',
    'custom_name' => 'c_n'
);

$callback = function($param, $other_param, $foo) {
    echo $param . " " . $other_param . " " . $foo; // output: p1 p2 c_n
}

$callback2 = function ($custom_name, $param1, $param2) {
    echo $custom_name . " " . $param1 . " " . $param2; // output: c_n p1 p2
}
```

---

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by `call_user_func_array` is "slow"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat using `call_user_func_array` is 124% slower than calling function directly (`function()`), calling with `ReflectionFunction` is 109% slower.

Comment: Before PHP 5.6, it seems like `call_user_func_array` was the way to go.  Not sure of any other method (other than `ReflectionFunction`, which I always thought was even slower).

Comment: You could use [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) within your callable

Comment: @ElefantPhace thanks for your suggestion, but it's will be hard to migrate :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.6, you can use the [`...` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) when calling your function.

```
$callable(...$args);
```

DEMO: https://3v4l.org/5KUNA

Comment: great suggestion, but I need to support PHP 5.5, and many users of this on 5.3-5.5, not 5.6.